# Looking for references for some remark of Quine's

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics, analytic-philosophy, philosophy-of-logic, quine

I'm looking for a comment I think I remember Quine having made. He's talking about our understanding of proofs. I think he says something along the following lines...
If you understand many different proofs of the same thing (say the completeness proof for FOL) you understand or comprehend the thing proved in a better way
I can't find it anywhere.

Hope you can help.

Comment: Maybe use the quote block text to separate out your paraphrase from the rest of the text, this way a reader can clearly distinguish where the quote begins and ends. This edit might help you find an answer.

Comment: The idea is not unique to Quine, Polya quipped "*It is better to solve one problem five different ways than to solve five problems one way*". http://letsplaymath.net/best-of-the-blog/quotations/

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps here.

http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/philosophy-mathematics/

Sincerely yours.
Aline Delves

Comment: Maybe you should narrow your answer down a bit to the section that has the quote you think the user is looking for?

Comment: I don't see it there.

Comment: First off welcome to philosophy.se. Link-only answers are strongly discouraged. If the answer is there, quote it here.